# How to call Kotlin/JS functions from regular Javascript?

Tags: javascript, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-js

I’ve been using Kotlin to develop a small 2D simulation software, and I’m using Kotlin multiplatform projects to make it run on both the JVM and in a browser. So far it works well.

However, I have a problem when I want to call functions defined in Kotlin/JS from regular Javascript.

To make my application work in the browser, I’m including the big JS file which is under the “build/distributions” folder after running the “build” Gradle task. When my Kotlin/JS application contains a *main()* function, this one is automatically being called when the HTML pag referencing the JS file is opened, and it works well.

But if I remove the main function and instead I create a *start()* function which is supposed to be called manually (after a click on a button, for instance), it does not work: it says the function *start()* is not defined even though it is declared in the Kotlin code.

After opening the generated JS file it seems that indeed there is no *start()* function. It looks like all the name of the functions have been minified.

I tried adding *@JsName*, but it didn’t change anything.

So I guess I’m doing something wrong, but I really don’t know what and how to make it work.

Note: I'm using Kotlin 1.3.70

EDIT: Here is the core of my build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("js") version "1.3.70-eap-184"
}


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

    maven(url = "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
}

dependencies {

}

kotlin {
    target {
        nodejs {

        }
        browser {
            webpackTask {
                mode = org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.webpack.KotlinWebpackConfig.Mode.PRODUCTION
                bin = "$projectDir/node_modules/$bin"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the function with the module name and qualified name:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-structure

```
package my.qualified.packagename

fun foo() = "Hello"
```

```
alert(myModule.my.qualified.packagename.foo());
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-to-kotlin-interop.html#jsname-annotation

> In some cases (for example, to support overloads), Kotlin compiler mangles names of generated functions and attributes in JavaScript code. To control the generated names, you can use the  `@JsName`  annotation

UPD: 
You have two ways to change the module name:

1) If you use gradle you can add this code to your `build.gradle`

```
compileKotlinJs {
    kotlinOptions.outputFile = "${rootDir}/web/app.js" // should be valid js variable name
}
```

or in your `build.gradle.kts`

```
kotlin {
    target {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.outputFile = "${rootDir}/web/app.js"
        }
    }
}
```

in this case you should use generated file (`app.js`) in the `web` folder
(you can use other folder and file names).

2) You should create folder `webpack.config.d` and create js file with any name, and content which configures library mode for `webpack`

```
config.output = config.output || {} // just in case where config.output is undefined
config.output.library = "libraryName" // should be valid js variable name
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the module name I should call. My module in Intellij IDEA is called 'sim-view-js'. Do I have to rename my Intellij module or is there a way to call 'sim-view-js.mypackage.foo()'?

Comment: You should call it `sim-view-js.mypackage.foo()` where `mypackage` is the name of your package.

Comment: sim-view-js is not a valid Javascript name. I can't call it this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm still facing some issues. Approach (1) is generating a module with the right name, but I can not easily include it in a HTML view as "module kotlin.js cannot be found". With approach (2) I have the name of my module clearly exposed, but the name of the functions are not exposed (in the webpack bundle I've "no static exports found" lines).

Comment: After new tests, approach (2) is working. It's just that I need to have a main() function, even if empty. Without this function, the other ones were not exposed. The main function must refer to the functions I want to expose. As I don't want these functions to be called, I've wrapped them in a if(false) {} statement.

Comment: @Fitz 2022 update: You don't need to refer to the functions, just mark them with `@JsExport` and DCE won't remove the functions :)